# 'nobody' own the file created through php

Tags: php, server-configuration

one of my customers uses a personal server that sets the default owner to 'nobody' so he can't write on or delete any of those files.
I have brutally solved this problem manually creating the needed files, but thi sin't a solution because I still need to craeted files with names that I can't forecast.

Is there any php solution or server configuration that I can provide to finally solve this problem?

Some images:

[image]

and

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the right permissions, you can set the group setuid bit on the directory with

`chmod g+rwxs dirname`

This will ensure that files created in the directory are owned by the group. You should then make sure everyone runs with umask 002 or 007.

[PHP CHMOD Link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php)

Comment: I have added the umask function, but I can't check because I haven't got the url of the site. However I would like to ask another thing: is it better to use `touch` instead of `file_put_contents` to create file?

Comment: @Dheed If you want to write data to ta file you use file_put_contents and if you want to just change the time on a file then use touch. Please note that touch will create a file if it does not exist. In your case I would use file_put_contents.

Comment: The problem is that I can't check because I can't reproduce this error and my costumer haven't given me the url to his website, but don't worry if it works I will mark your answer

Answer (score -1):

The files get written as the user the web server is running under. in your case `nobody` is the user that the web server is running

Comment: -1 for pointing out the obvious, a solution to the problem is what the OP asked not whats happening.